# md5 returns empty string

Tags: php, md5

First of all I searched on Google and didn't find any help to my problem.

I'm working on my local server with MAMP and I'm following a tutorial to try securing a php page with md5.

In my login.php page there is a form with login/password fields which calls a JS function when submitted:

```
<form id='log' method='post' action='templates/auth.php' onsubmit='javascript:submit_pass();'> 
<input type='hidden' name='md5' /> 
<table align='center'> 
<tr><td>Login</td><td><input name='login' /></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Mot de passe</td><td><input type='password' name='passwd' /></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' value='Login !' /></td></tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

The login.js script called on submit:

```
function submit_pass()
{
  pass=document.forms['log'].passwd.value;
  document.forms['log'].passwd.value="";
  buf=MD5(pass);
  document.forms['log'].md5.value=buf;

  return true;
}
```

Then it sends the parameters by POST to auth.php

So I type in the fields a random login and password.

On my auth.php page I echo $_POST['login'] and $_POST['md5']

The problem is that $_POST['md5'] is empty. So I try to echo its size and it appears 0!

I don't undrestand, is something missing? Wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `buf=MD5(pass);` -- where's the `MD5` function?

Comment: Don't bother hashing passwords before transmitting them over the network; you won't gain any security by that. If I can capture the password hash, I can also capture the session cookie or use rainbow tables to find out the password. Use HTTPS instead.

Comment: please don't use MD5 for hashing password.

Comment: Just to add on, when your password gets to the backend, make sure you use a real password hashing algorithm (such as the one provided with PHP's `password_hash()` function) and not MD5.

Answer (score 1):

Do not hash the password on the client. It will not improve security, because nothing has changed: The server can only see the MD5 hash and the username now, and if I can intercept that, I have everything I need to also log in! Because the server can only check the MD5.

Additionally, Javascript does not come with a built in MD5 function.

And on top of that: An unsalted MD5 hash is as insecure as the plain text password itself - it is only marginally more effort to scan the whole password space.

If you really want to improve password security, you have to use SSL for the client-server-communication (otherwise anything is sent as clear text), and on the server you should hash with the new and shiny [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/password_hash) function of PHP 5.5 (and there is a [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) that allows you to do it starting with PHP 5.3.7).

Answer (score 0):

For passwords you should use crypt(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php